# How to let component.ts load data before template is loaded?

Tags: angular

I have error on my template which gives many parse errors which I get from early loading of template. Please help!

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProjectDetails();
    }

    getProjectDetails() {
        this.productId.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

        this.amen.getProjectDetails(this.productId).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.handleResponse(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                this.error = error.error.error;
            }
        );
    }

    handleResponse(response) {
        console.log('Pro Details---------------', response);
        this.productDetails = {
            image: response.responseData.project_image,
            title: response.responseData.name,
            date: response.responseData.created_at,
            amount: response.responseData.amount,
            description: response.responseData.description,
            video_url: response.responseData.video_url
        };
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please mentioned that as well!

Answer (score 4):

just check if your productDetails is truthy before using it inside your html :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="productDetails">
{{ productDetails.title }}
...

</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Z.Balbol said, at first check truthy of productDetails variable. You can also use this syntax:

```
<ng-container>
{{ productDetails?.title }}
...

</ng-container>
```